# NodeJS supertest access to session object

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, mocha.js, supertest

I'm testing my Node.js application with supertest. In my controller I access the session object. In order to make a valid request this session object needs to be filled with some data.

**Controller**

```
        // determine whether it is user's own profile or not
        var ownProfile = userId == req.session.user._id ? true : false;
```

**Test**

```
it('profile', function (done) {
    testUserOne.save(function(error, user){

        request
            .agent(server)
            .get('/profile?userId=' + user._id)
            .expect('Content-Type', /html/)
            .expect(200)
            .expect(/Profile/)
            .end(done);
    })
});
```

**Question**

How can I mock the req/session object?

Answer (score 16):

just use as sub-app, and call your authenticated() at parent-app:

```
var mockApp = express();
mockApp.use(session);
mockApp.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    //authenticated(req, res, next);
    //OR
    req.session.uid = 'mock uid';
    next();
});
mockApp.use(app);
```

all your routes will be authenticated before matched!

Comment: Interesting option. What is the purpose of mockApp.use(app)? Don't we have to link the mockApp to the main express?

Comment: @nishant `mockApp.use(app)` actually extends mockApp with the original app, so the session overriding handler is inserted into the original app. Worth noting that it's `mockApp` that should be used in the tests: `request(mockApp)…`. Thx for pointing that out!

Comment: could you add the instantiation of session?

Comment: @JRichardsz For me it's enough to instantiate `express-session` with a secret:
`mockApp.use(session({secret: 'test-secret'}));`

Answer (score 14):

This new lib should do the trick:

- https://github.com/rjz/supertest-session

You might also have a look at [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) that is part of [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest). Here's a nice tutorial on this:

- http://jaketrent.com/post/authenticated-supertest-tests/

Don't want another lib? Try this one ...

- https://gist.github.com/joaoneto/5152248

Comment: Please note the Jake Trent tutorial is outdated as `saveCookies` has been deprecated: https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/1014