# Generate test session manually with express-session

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I have implemented the OAUth 2.0 flow as single authentication method for my express application.

In real situation, once a user connected using OAuth, a session is created and accessible server-side in `req.session.passport`.

In this session, there is the OAuth access token that is required to perform authenticated requests on my REST API. To be able to do so, I wrote a middleware that copies the token from `req.session.passport` to the `Authorization` header.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.passport) {
    req.headers['Authorization'] = req.session.passport.user.accessToken;
  }
  next();
});
```

Now, I would like to test this middleware without going through the entire oauth flow. Ideally, I would like to create a session manually and inject test data inside `req.session.passport`, then call any protected endpoint of my API to check that it can correctly perform authenticated requests.

I tried to manually set data inside `req.session` in the following test

```
it('Should be able to make an authenticated request with session data',
function(done) {
  var req = request(app).get('/api/SomeProtectedEndpoint');

  req.session = {
    passport: {
      user: {
        accessToken : 'eade123d3ffwhatever'
      }
    }
  }

  req.expect(200, function(err, res){
      if (err) return done(err);
      done();
    });
});
```

But if I display the contents of `req.session` inside my middleware, the manual data is gone. I believe it is removed by `express-session`.

How can I manually inject session data in a request for testing purposes ?

Comment: same case here.. have you resolve this issue ?

Comment: hey checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213674/nodejs-supertest-access-to-session-object . Both answers are really useful for this case.